# how to VLOOKUP a measure result in DAX Power BI

Tags: filter, powerbi, dax, vlookup

i have Excel Dashboard like this
[image]

i want to replicate this in PBI but the result is not the same
[image]

in my PBI measure, the Total SKU is

```
Total SKU = CALCULATE( DISTINCTCOUNT(CSDPVSXML[ProductId]), 
                                    ALL('DT Active'), NOT( ISBLANK(CSDPVSXML[ProductId])))

Total SKU 2 = CALCULATE( DISTINCTCOUNT(CSDPVSXML[ProductId]), NOT( ISBLANK(CSDPVSXML[ProductId])))
```

Total SKU XML 2 using the same DAX script as Total SKU, is there a way to achieve the same result as the excel version, since i cant vlookup in PBI into DAX result, lookup function in PBI only lokup into predefined table, not the result of a measure

[image]
[image]
[image]

thank you in advanced

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LookUP is working only with a table, not with a visual. Looking through your question, I assume that you just need to exclude distributor value from filtering.
Try this code:

```
Total SKU 2 =
    CALCULATE(
        [Total SKU]
        ,ALL(tblName[DISTRIBUTOR])
    )
```

new measure

```
Total SKU 2 =
    CALCULATE(
        [Total SKU]
        ,CSDPVSXML[AreaOfPricing]=SELECTEDVALUE(Customer Hierarky[Format Level 3])
        ,ALL(tblName[DISTRIBUTOR])
    )
```

Comment: CALCULATE(
        [Total SKU]
        ,ALL(CSDPVSXML[DISTRIBUTOR])
    )
if i write like this DAX script, it will return all AreaofPricing and DT CODE, not juts Area Pricing that exist in left table that lookup to, but the value is already showing the right number, 18

Comment: Hi, the main problem for the solution is a lack of your data model structure understanding. What I see is that  in `AreaofPricing` visual you are filtering your measure with filters on the top and with the Value in the row of `AreaofPricing` column.  I also guess that you 
 use an other table and column for `Sales Format Level 3` not the same as for `AreaofPricing` .  If  I'm correct please let me know `tblName[ColName]` for `AreaofPricing` and  `tblName[ColName]`  for  `Sales Format Level 3`. Or add your tables structures to the question body and let me know if it's done.

Comment: yes its from other table, i've added the model in the question body

Comment: how does `Format Level 3` comes? Is it a `Product Hierarky[SKU CODE]` column?

Comment: sales level format comes from Customer Hierarky table like in the model picture i added

Comment: oh, I see. Thanx. But how comes `D36406` for instance, what its column name for both visuals. It's not a `DISTRIBUTOR` and looks like `SKU CODE`?

Comment: What its column name in `CSDPVSXML`?

Comment: its AreaOfPricing column in CSDPVSXL table

Comment: yes its some kind of sku, the idea of this dashboard is to know which distributor that having missing sku

Comment: Try a `new measure` I added to the answer body

Comment: it throws error `A function 'CONTAINSROW' has been used in a True/False expression that is used as a table filter expression. This is not allowed.` i add the screenshot in question body

Comment: then change string with IN to `CSDPVSXML[AreaOfPricing]=SELECTEDVALUE(Customer Hierarky[Format Level 3])`

Comment: `    CALCULATE(
        [Total SKU]
        ,CSDPVSXML[AreaOfPricing] IN VALUE( CSDPVSXML[AreaOfPricing] = SELECTEDVALUE(Customer Hierarky[Format Level 3]))
    )`
like this ?

Comment: no, just replace the string. I changed it in the answer

Comment: sorry, but the one that should be showing '18' is Total SKU  XML 2, not the Total SKU measure

Comment: But you use `[Total SKU]` for the  left visual, yes?

Comment: yes, but for total sku 2 it should be 17, i tried your first script in Total SKU XML 2, and it works !

Comment: a changed the second measure. Test it

Comment: Did we solve the issue?

Comment: sorry, maybe im not too good to explain the problem im facing in the question body, so in the left visual i disntict count the number of sku in customer hierarky table and filter out the Status of the DT, thats why i use ALL function, but in Total SKU 2 i let the Status DT filter the measure, so i removed the ALL filter in Total SKU, and in the Total SKU XML 2 is kinda like VLOOKUP to the left visual, i used your first script to the TOTAL SKU XML 2 and it works

Comment: yes, we solved the issue, thank you very much ! a little bit oot, do yo know some good course to learn DAX, i kinda lost in filter function, row context etc

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm happy to help you. May be I could be a little bit smarter ). Happy new year!

Comment: this is the best resource, I think - https://www.sqlbi.com. I can recommend you to read The Definitive Guide to DAX. It will take time to read and understand, but it's a great book about DAX https://www.sqlbi.com/books/the-definitive-guide-to-dax-2nd-edition/